# I am not able to access DOM element which I am creating using ngFor loop and I am getting the data from the service. Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, dom, service

I am facing an issue related DOM Manipulation in angular. I have defined one array named colors in my component and then I am calling the service method and getting the colors data from the server and then assigning them into the colors array inside subscribe method. In HTML template using *ngFor loop, I am displaying that colors array data. Now I want to add some dynamic class or style to the HTML elements and for that, I am using ElementRef to access this element but I am not able to access it because the colors array is undefined initially. Now let me attach the code...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: "<div><li class="color" *ngFor="let color of colors">{{color}}</li></div>",
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] 
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
   colors:any;

   constructor(private elementRef:ElementRef, private renderer:Renderer2) {}
   
   ngOnInit():void {
     setTimeout(() => {
        this.colors = ['red', 'yellow', 'green'];
     }, 1000);
   }

   ngAfterViewInit():void {
     const color = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('.color');
     console.log(color);
   }
}
```

Here I am using the setTimeout function in this code which is behaving like a service because the service takes some time in getting the data from the server but in my code, I am using service.

Now If I am opening console in Developer Tools then I am getting NodeList [] this means I am not able to access DOM Element. I know the issue I am not able to access DOM element because my code for accessing DOM Element is running before the data assigning to the colors array and by default or initially colors array is undefined or empty. That's why I am getting NodeList [] in the console. But I am not able to understand how to solve this problem?.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `ngAfterViewInit` calls before the timeout you set in `ngOnInit` finished.

I would go with [`ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) approach which is more reliable.
Here's an example:

```js
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li #color *ngFor="let color of (colors$ | async)">{{ color }}</li>
    </ul>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent implements OnDestroy, AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren("color") colors: QueryList<ElementRef<HTMLLIElement>>;
  colors$: Observable<string[]> = of(["red", "green", "blue"]).pipe(
    delay(3000)
  );

  private colorsSubscription = Subscription.EMPTY;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.colors.changes.subscribe(list => {
      list.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.nativeElement);
      });
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.colorsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

What we are doing in this example is:

- Initializing `colors$` to fire a string array after 3 seconds
- Subscribing to `colors$` with `AsyncPipe` and displaying the colors
- Setting `ViewChildren` to query for all elements with `#color` template reference
- Subscribing to `QueryList` changes (additions / deletes etc) and acting accordingly

You can find the complete example in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-t2mun1)

Comment: yes, but if I am trying to access the first element using this code inside the ngAfterViewInit method.    code:  console.log(this.colors.toArray[0].nativeElement);   I am not able to access it then how will I add a new style to this element.

Comment: This is because you cannot access the list in the changes by index. You can, for example iterate the elements using `forEach`. I've updated the example to show this.

Answer (score 1):

You need `ngAfterViewCHecked`. This will run every time Angular has finished running change detection on a component and it's children

Secondly there is error in `template`. If you are using all double quotes `"` that will terminate the string. You need t use single quote and double quotes for all attributes like this

```
'<div><li class="color" *ngFor="let color of colors">{{color}}</li></div>'
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yw74mt)

Comment: yes, but the problem with ngafterViewChecked is it running the whole code inside this every time and making the application laggy or slow For Example: check this code Link :   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qsy5ma?file=src/app/app.component.ts